# Jira error “The value 'XXX' does not exist for the field 'project'.” when sharing a JQL search string with another user

Tags: jira

I sent a Jira search link to two colleagues, but instead of results they get this error:
[image]

I used the [Permission Helper](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver/jira-admin-helper-938847791.html#JiraAdminHelper-PermissionHelper) to confirm that these users do, indeed, have access to the project. Why can't they see the results?

(NOTE: Unlike [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39167356/jira-rest-error-the-value-xxx-does-not-exist-for-the-field-project-while), I am not trying to access JIRA programmatically. I'm just sending a search url via email.)

Answer (score 2):

To answer my own question, it turns out both of these users had simply not logged in yet for the morning! Slightly embarrassing to admit how long it took me to figure this out! I decided to leave this clue behind for anyone else who faces this.